Error while populating 'parentcustomerid' field in dataverse from Azure SQL DB table
I am currently utilizing the Data Flow activity to transfer data from Azure SQL Database to the Dataverse database. In this process, I am populating the parentcustomerid using a derived column with the following formula:
Column: parentcustomerid@odata.bind
Expression: concat('/accounts(', parentcustomerid, ')')
However, I am encountering the following error:
Job Failure Reason
{   "error": {     "code": "0x80048d19",     "message": "Error identified in Payload provided by the user for Entity: 'contacts'. For more information on this error, please follow this help link: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2195293",     "InnerException": "Microsoft.OData.ODataException: An undeclared property 'parentcustomerid' which only has property annotations in the payload but no property value was found in the payload. In OData, only declared navigation properties and declared named streams can be represented as properties without values."   } }
I would appreciate any guidance on this.
Thanks
I have tried using this expression in deriveed column
Column: parentcustomerid@odata.bind
Expression: concat('/accounts(', parentcustomerid, ')')

As per this documentation,

The cause of this error is the invalid navigation property in the request. When the used single-valued navigation parentcustomerid is not present in the given entity type, you will get this type of error.

Also, check whether the current column parentcustomerid is a single-valued navigation property or a multi table lookup.
To avoid this, as per the same documentation, you need to ensure the navigation property exists in the CSDL $metadata document.
You can go through the similar SO answer by @user17390749.

Thanks @Rakesh Govindula, it was a multi lookup and the similar question helped me with that.
